# Cant Install ubuntu on my HP laptop!

Tags: boot, windows

Ok so I am trying to install Ubuntu either side by side with windows 8 or completely remove windows 8 because I hate it!

I have disabled Secure boot, and I have tried making a USB bootable device, exactly the way ubuntu wanted me to. I tried dual-booting it too with wubi. I have tried it all and its just not working :(

When I try to boot it off my external harddrive it doesn't boot up, just says can not find OS. And when I used wubi it kept saying wubildr.mbr file is missing. I have tried everything and read so many forum posts.

Help would be GREATLY appreciated! I really don't like windows8. OH and by the way everything I tried above works perfectly fine with my windows 7 machine. Just makes me even more pissed off at windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

FOR HP users
If you want to replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu. Download the ISO and burn that to a disc using Nero or InfraRecorder (Infrarecorder is free).

Then restart your laptop. Insert the DVD and press F9 to change the boot loading option.
Select - "Internal CD/DVD ROM" and press ENTER

Laptop will start booting form DVD and the proceed with installation. While installing there is an option for "Replacing windows8 with Ubuntu". Select this option.

Thats it. After successfull installation, let the DVD tray to come out. Remove DVD and close tray and press ENTER.

Comment: Problem is on my laptop theres no CD/DVD drive at all. Am I screwed?